# Layer filtered by a slider

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a map style created with Mapbox and added a source with a geojson data with Mapbox GL JS.
I want to create a filter slider to show the data by years. In the geojson, this years are on a string feature ("2020", "2021", "2022").
And in the code I added an arrow with the years: ["2020","2021","2022"].
I've got the slider and show the text of the arrow ("2020") and I've got the filter of the map and run if I change, in the code, the position of the arrow (if I write in the code of the filter "arrowname[2]" the map show the data of the year 2022).
But, when I play with the slider, the text of the year changes, but the data isn't filtered.
What's wrong?
Here, the code:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div class='map-overlay' id='legend'>
<div class="map-overlay-inner">
<b>Incendios por año</b>
<input type="range" min="0" max="2" value="0" id="miSlider">
<p id="textano"></p>
</div>
</div>

<script>

// the arrow
var anos = [
"2020",
"2021",
"2022"
];

// the slider
var slider = document.getElementById("miSlider"),
    output = document.getElementById("textano");
slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = anos[this.value];
    const anoslider = anos[this.value];
    return anoslider;
}

// the filter
var filterano = ['==', ['string', ['get', 'ano_ok']], slider.oninput()];

// After "new mapboxgl.Map..."
map.on('load', function() {

// The geojson source
map.addSource('incendios', {
'type': 'geojson',
'data': 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/encarnihinojosa/mapasSUR/main/1975_2022_And.json'
});

// the source's layer
map.addLayer({
'id': 'incendios-layer',
'type': 'fill',
'source': 'incendios',
'paint': {
'fill-color': 'rgba(252, 34, 34, 0.5)',
'fill-outline-color': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'},
// Filter application
'filter': ['all', filterano]
});
});
</script>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the problem.
The slider's function was wrong.
This is the correct function:

```
slider.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  map.setFilter('incendios-layer', ['==', ['string', ['get', 'ano_ok']], slider.oninput()]);
});
```

I hope someone finds it helpful.